# Search in SSP giving error 

Tags: search-scope, infrastructure, administration

While accesing Search scoped in SSP of web application, I am getting the following error:

*"The search service is currently offline. Visit the Services on Server page in SharePoint Central Administration to verify whether the service is enabled. This might also be because an indexer move is in progress. "*

Could you please provide a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing what the error describes? In Services On Server page in Central Administration you can check what services are running.